# fread and zcat issues

Tags: r, ubuntu, data.table

I'm using R 3.4.3 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Due to filesize limitations I have to provide a dummy example.

Last night I was doing this and it worked (no updates or changes since then):

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("zcat 5gb-file.csv.gz")
```

Now I am doing this:

```
library(data.table)
data1 <- fread("zcat 200mb-file.csv.gz")
data2 <- fread("zcat 100mb-file.csv.gz")
```

And it returns the error `/dev/shm/file123456 not found`.

I have more than 1TB free on /home and ~40GB free on /.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Can you execute the following command at your linux command prompt and see what size is your shm: `df -h |grep shm`

Comment: thanks @Katia it returns 3.9GB while I am trying to zcat a 200MB file

Comment: What is used and avail values in the output? The output should look something like: `tmpfs                 127G   17G  111G  13% /dev/shm`. The first value (127GB) in my case is total size, then 17GB is used and 111GB is available memory. The fact that your input file is 200MB means that when it is unziped it will probably use more than 10 times more RAM. Shm is used by other processes and so you might not have enough space in shm. Did you try to use  read.csv() or read_csv() function? What size of RAM do you have on your machine?

Comment: One more suggestion: What you can try is to read just a part of a file  using nrows argument to fread() and see if this succeeds for relatively small number (like nrows=10) and then if it works increase number of records.

Comment: thanks a lot again @Katia, I saw that and in my case the decompressed CSV is around 200MB, compresed it used 18MB, also I am using around 8% of shm which has 128GB asigned... I tried read_csv() and it works but returns reading errors where fread() is robust.... I guess I have to format the computer after this magically happened